# TestNG up to 6.10 ignores subsequent classes in a suite if @BeforeMethod fails

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

Consider the following *TestNG* suite:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name = "TestNG Examples" parallel = "false" thread-count = "1">
    <test name = "TestNG Examples">
        <classes>
            <class name = "com.example.A"/>
            <class name = "com.example.B"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

consisting of these classes:

```java
package com.example;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public final class A extends AbstractTest {
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
    }
}
```

and

```java
package com.example;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public final class B extends AbstractTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("B.test()");
    }
}
```

Note that `B.test()` is executed after `A.test()`, and both classes have a common super class:

```java
package com.example;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;

public abstract class AbstractTest {
    @AfterMethod
    public final void tearDown() {
    }
}
```

Now, if a `@BeforeMethod` hook in `A` fails for some reason (as in the above example), subsequent suite classes extending the same super class (`AbstractTest`) are never run:

[image: TestNG Eclipse plug-in]

This is a screenshot of *Eclipse*, but I'm observing the same behaviour in *IntelliJ IDEA* and *TeamCity*, too.

The following preconditions must be met in order to reproduce this issue:

- Both tests should have a common ancestor.
- The common ancestor should have an `@AfterMethod` hook.
- The first test class being run should have a failing `@BeforeMethod` hook.

Is this the intended behaviour?
Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: I confirm the issue. Could you open a ticket on https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/ ?

Comment: What version of TestNG is this ? I tried using 6.11 and I don't seem to be able to reproduce the problem. @juherr what version did you try ?

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan I use the master branch but not yet up2date. I only  reproduced the issue with a suite file.

Comment: @juherr - The expectation should be that the test method and the aftermethod should run for the class `B` and it happens for me. Please see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/krmahadevan/855b8816ccd9996ec69b06091fa3a3f4) wherein I have created a full fledged sample along with the assertions. I am running this on 6.11 and it works.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan I answered on the gist

Comment: @juherr Even I am able to reproduce it. Thanks

Comment: @juherr I was only able to reproduce the issue using **6.10** and older versions. **6.11**, on the other hand, doesn't seem affected.

For **6.10** and below, adding `alwaysRun=true` to the `@AfterMethod` hook does indeed work the problem around (see the answer by [murali selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4856814/murali-selenium)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check alwaysRun here http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html.

If we want to run methods even if dependent method fails then use alwaysRun=true

Comment: Only required for _TestNG_ **6.10** and below. _TestNG_ **6.11** is not affected by the issue.